# Jade != css() and != js() notation?

Tags: pug

I was browsing the source for [hackathon-starter](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter), and opening the jade layout template showed:

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    meta(name='description', content='')
    meta(name='csrf-token', content=_csrf)
    meta(name='author', content='')
    title #{title} | Hackathon Starter
    != css('styles')
  body
    include partials/navbar

    .container
      include partials/flash
      block content

    include partials/footer

    != js('application')
```

I was wondering what the `!= css('styles')` and `!= js('application')` means, because I can't find any similar syntax in the jade docs.

Answer (score 2):

It's part of [connect-assets](https://github.com/adunkman/connect-assets)

> ### Markup functions
>
> connect-assets provides three global functions named `js`, `css`, and `assetPath`. Use them in your views. They return the HTML markup needed to include the most recent version of your assets (or, the path to the asset), taking advantage of caching when available. For instance, in a [Jade template](http://jade-lang.com/), the code
>
> ```
> != css("normalize")
> != js("jquery")
> ```
>
> (where `!=` is Jade's syntax for running JS and displaying its output) results in the markup
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize-[hash].css">
> <script src="/js/jquery-[hash].js"></script>
> ```